# Is Einstein's theory really challenged by the recent paper in news?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, speed-of-light, big-bang

A [recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1603.03312) authored by Niayesh Afshordi and Joao Magueijo is in the news claiming to challenge Einstein's theory on constancy of light speed. It says light might have travelled with a faster pace during the initial stages of Big bang which apparently sets aside the inflation hypothesis.

My question is whether it actually invalidates Einstein's relativity - which depends on constancy of speed of light. Or is it only applicable to the very early universe?

Answer (score 40):

Magueijo came up with the variable speed of light idea nearly twenty years ago. The motivation was as a way of explaining the homogeneity of the universe. At that time inflation was still somewhat controversial (perhaps it still is) and Magueijo's theory was mainly intended as an alternative to inflation.

Since then inflation has become more accepted and VSL theories generally became less popular. However there are beginning to be mutterings that inflation is such a vague theory that it's impossible to experimentally prove. That is, the theory has so many adjustable parameters it's hard to see what experimental data would conclusively rule it out. It is in this context that VSL theories are attracting more attention again.

But it must be emphasised that there is no experimental evidence that conclusively rules out or rules in either inflation or VSL theories. They both remain ideas that explain some features in an appealing way, but neither is more than an appealing idea right now.

As for the conflict with general relativity, both theories are concerned with the very earliest moments after the Big Bang, and I suspect most physicists already doubt that GR will hold right back to the Big Bang itself. We expect some quantum gravity to become important at very early times. So I'm not sure I'd say VSL thories challenge GR.

The new element in Magueijo's paper is a firm prediction about the effect of VSL on the cosmic microwave background. While the current measurements of the CMB aren't precise enough to test Magueijo's predicitions the next generation of measurements may be. However even if the measurements match Magueijo's prediction that will show only that his VSL theory is possible not that it's true. His predicted value for the spectral index would still also be compatible with a range of inflationary theories.

Comment: In your opinion, what does Occam's razor suggest? "The simplest explanation of all observations is usually the right one." "So many adjustable parameters" is usually a bad omen for a fundamental theory...

Comment: I would argue that inflation isn't a "theory". However what is inarguable is that is *always* "impossible to experimentally prove" a theory.  I think you mean almost impossible to falsify.

Comment: There _is_ experimental evidence for VSL theories: optical clocks go slower when they're lower. See the [David Wineland interview](https://www.learner.org/courses/physics/scientist/transcripts/wineland.html): _"if one clock in one lab is 30 centimeters higher than the clock in the other lab, we can see the difference in the rates they run at"_.   An optical clock is not some cosmic gas meter with time flowing through it. It goes slower when it's lower because light goes slower when it's lower,  not for any other reason.

Comment: That's the [coordinate speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_light_in_non-inertial_reference_frames) not the local speed of light. We all agree the coordinate speed of light varies - the best proof of this is gravitational lensing which happens for exactly this reason. However that is not what Magueijo's theory states. His theory states that the speed of light is no longer **locally** invariant.

Comment: Basically, there are three types of statements in science, "disproven", "not disproven yet", and "cannot be disproven, so let's ignore it"?

Comment: I don't quite agree with your fourth paragraph. I don't quite understand the PRD in full, but it does seem quite committed to a 'bimetric' theory, which sounds to me like a definitive break with strict GR. That it only happens in regimes where people expect GR to break down is a separate matter. On the other side, I'm less clear on how compatible inflation actually is with GR.

Comment: @JanDvorak Seems so. The latter, "cannot be disproven", basically means "does not rule out any possibilities". What use, and what predictive power, would have a theory that does not tag _anything_ as being impossible?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I'd put them as, "outdated", "currently seems to make the most sense" and "who knows".

Comment: @John Rennie : Einstein called it the speed of light rather than the coordinate speed of light. The local speed of light is only constant because of the [tautology](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4507)  wherein the local motion of light is used to define the second and the metre, which are then used to measure... the local motion of light. Duh! So when it comes to deciding between what you say and what Einstein said, I'll go for Einstein thanks.

Comment: @JohnDuffield: it's not a tautology. If I give you a metre long measuring rod and a clock then you can measure how long light takes to travel from one end of your rod to the other and thereby measure the velocity of light. Everywhere you take the rod and clock in a curved spacetime you will measure the same velocity, using the same rod and the same clock. You can use any kind of clock, clockwork, atomic, whatever, and likewise anything for your measuring rod. It doesn't matter. You will always measure the velocity of light to me $c$.

Comment: @John Rennie : it is a [tautology](https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4507). You measure the speed of light to be c when you're using an optical clock. Go to a lower location where light goes slower, and your optical clock goes slower too. The same goes for an atomic clock, which is in essence a microwave optical clock. The same goes for a piezoelectric clock because you're still dealing with electromagnetism. The same goes for a clockwork clock because of the wave nature of matter. Einstein was not wrong. If you're saying he was, you're in the same camp as Pentcho Valev.

Answer (score -12):

> Is Einstein's theory really challenged by the recent paper in news?

No. Because Einstein's theory is a VSL theory. See the [Einstein digital papers](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol7-trans/156?highlightText=%22spatially%20variable%22). Einstein wrote this in 1920, note the second paragraph:

[image]

He said the curvature of light rays can only occur in spaces where the speed of light is spatially variable. Also see the [Shapiro delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro_delay) where you can read that according to the general theory, the speed of a light wave depends on the strength of the gravitational potential along its path. Anybody who tells you the speed of light doesn't vary is telling you about "modern" GR which isn't in line with Einstein's GR. They might insist it is, but it isn't.

> A recent paper authored by Niayesh Afshordi and Joao Magueijo is in the news claiming to challenge Eintein's theory on contancy of light speed. It says light might have travelled with a faster pace during the initial stages of Big bang

I fear they've got this wrong. Light goes slower when it's lower. Because the energy density is higher. So light in the early universe should have gone slower too. If they say it went faster, then IMHO they're misunderstanding Einstein's theory rather than challenging it.

> which apparently sets aside the inflation hypothesis.

Inflation is under some pressure these days. See [Physicist Slams Cosmic Theory He Helped Conceive](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cross-check/physicist-slams-cosmic-theory-he-helped-conceive/) where Paul Steinhardt is rather critical. Personally I rather think that when you understand GR correctly, you just don't need inflation - it's a solution to a problem that doesn't exist.

> My question is whether it actually invalidates Einstein's relativity which depends on constancy of speed of light.

No it doesn't, because Einstein's relativity doesn't depend on the constancy of the speed of light. Another article worth reading is [Is The Speed of Light Everywhere the Same?](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/speed_of_light.html) by Don Koks on the "Baez" PhysicsFAQ website. The answer is no.

> Or is it only applicable to the very early universe?

I know of no reason why it should be.

Comment: The authors didn't misunderstand Einstein's theory. Whether it predicts the speed of light should be constant or slower in the early universe, they are clearly still challenging that hypothesis by saying there's a possibility it was faster (challenge by contradiction). Furthermore, the constancy is present in GR because it uses $c$ as a constant value everywhere. It's not the observed speed that this paper suggests is changing, it's the locally valid speed. The value of $c$ itself is theorized to be variable; a function of time. Something not seen at all in Einstein's GR

Comment: The reason we might consider it valid to only the very early universe is that the constancy of the local speed of light is consistent with so many observations. True, the observed speed can change when viewed from a different gravitational potential; it can be spatially variable, but this talks about temporal variability

Comment: The quote you posted, in fact, confirms that the speed of light is locally constant for appropriate local coordinate systems on any world line. That's what everyone means when they say it's constant. And it was assumed by GR that the very early universe followed this idea and that the speed of light was locally the same in any given frame throughout that period. The paper asserts that it could be faster in the past, which means to say the speed in even a proper Minkowski frame at those early times would be faster than $c$. Not as a result of local gravitational disturbances

Comment: Fot the avoidance of doubt, GR is not a VSL theory in the sense Magueijo uses the term. GR is founded on the principle that the manifold is everywhere locally Minkowski, and this means the speed of light is everywhere locally equal to $c$. This is what is meant by the speed of light being constant. The article cited is referring to the coordinate speed of light, and that can indeed vary dramatically from $c$. In a VSL theory this principle of local invariance no longer holds. That is the key difference between a VSL theory and GR.

Comment: @Jim : a gravitational wave is an example of a temporal variability in the speed of light. Check out [gravitational waves and pulsars](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=EUM_VY2-Juiq8wfv_oCgDA&gws_rd=ssl#q=gravitational+wave+pulsars). Distant pulsars appear to go faster as the gravitational wave passes through you, because your optical clocks go slower, and so do you. Also see https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4507 where Magueijo and Moffat refer to the tautology wherein we use the local motion of light to define our second and our metre, and then use them to measure the  local motion of light.

Comment: I don't need to refer to that tautology because the definitions of metre and second were not invoked here. As for the pulsar thing, that is still spatial variability. The speed of light is varying in certain locations. The phenomenon causing this is transient, which makes the variance have an indirect time dependence, but it's not the same as saying "Even in a minkowskian region of space, the speed of light would appear variable"

Comment: @John Rennie : see the excerpt in my answer above where Einstein says special relativity is _"nowhere precisely realized in the real world". The theory of special relativity is only valid in the infinitesimal. The speed of light is only constant only in the infinitesimal. The falling observer can't measure the first-derivative of potential change in c directly, but he is  subject to the second-derivative-of potential tidal force which cannot be transformed away. See my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191753/76162) where I refer to Einstein saying this.

Comment: @Jim: IMHO you should note that the tautology is the reason why you can't measure any local change in c, be it varying spatially or temporally. No, the gravitational wave isn't the same as the expanding universe, but it is a situation where spatial-energy density varies over time. In the expanding universe, conservation of energy says the spatial energy-density continually reduces. This is akin to moving away from a black hole, but swapping space for time. NB: I know people talk of dark energy, but I know of no situations where energy is not conserved.

Comment: Conservation of energy would mean the energy density falls off like $\frac{1}{a^3}$. This is true of matter; however, the energy density of radiation falls off like $\frac{1}{a^4}$, which means even if you ignore the approximately constant energy density of dark energy, you still need to acknowledge that the total energy contained in matter and radiation (radiation referring to any energy moving at relativistic speeds) is decreasing in an expanding universe

Comment: And once again, the constancy of the speed of light was experimentally determined BEFORE the definitions of metre and second were changed to refer to it. We knew it was constant so we redefined to remove the uncertainty from $c$, not to enforce its constancy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; further discussion of the points already made will be moved to chat.

Answer (score -16):

Einstein's 1905 constant-speed-of-light postulate is false indeed but Magueijo's claim that the speed of light was faster in the past has nothing to do with it. Einstein's postulate asserts that the speed of light is the same for any observer, stationary or moving - an assertion that is easy to disprove, in the following way:

The initially stationary observer (receiver) starts moving towards the light source with speed v:

http://www.einstein-online.info/images/spotlights/doppler/doppler_static.gif (stationary observer)

http://www.einstein-online.info/images/spotlights/doppler/doppler_detector_blue.gif (moving observer)

Two hypotheses are conceivable:

Hypothesis 1 (Newton's emission theory): The speed of the light relative to the observer shifts from c to c'=c+v.

Hypothesis 2 (Einstein's relativity): The speed of the light relative to the observer does not shift (c'=c).

In order to test the two hypotheses, the observer measures the frequency - it shifts from f to

f' = c'/λ = (c+v)/λ = f(1+v/c) :

Quote: "Moving Observer. Now suppose the source is fixed but the observer is moving towards the source, with speed v. In time t, ct/λ waves pass a fixed point. A moving point adds another vt/λ. So f'=(c+v)/λ."

Quote: "Now let's see what this does to the frequency of the light. We know that even without special relativity, observers moving at different velocities measure different frequencies. (This is the reason the pitch of an ambulance changes as it passes you it doesn't change if you're on the ambulance). This is called the Doppler shift, and for small relative velocity v it is easy to show that the frequency shifts from f to f(1+v/c) (it goes up heading toward you, down away from you). There are relativistic corrections, but these are negligible here."

Clearly, measurements of the Doppler effect confirm Hypothesis 1 and refute Hypothesis 2. Einstein's relativity is based on a false postulate and will have to be discarded altogether.

Comment: Then how do you explain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_special_relativity ?

Comment: Yeah, the special theory of relativity perfectly predicts and explains the doppler effect from moving sources/detectors. If you're going to refute a theory by showing that it isn't supported by observations, try using observations that aren't explicitly predicted and well explained by that theory

Comment: See [this Baez article](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SpeedOfLight/speed_of_light.html) where Don Koks explains that c is not even constant in special relativity:  _"the speed of light depends on position when measured by a non-inertial observer is a fact routinely used by laser gyroscopes that form the core of some inertial navigation systems...  Making observations from an inertial frame... produces a speed of light that is always c... but the accelerated frame is more natural to our description of the world around us.  After all, we don't live our lives in free fall"_.